# Calling registerForActivityResult with Context

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an application and I need to call Calling registerForActivityResult from a class using Context?

Comment: Sorry, you need to use a `ComponentActivity`, not some other `Context`.

Comment: @CommonsWare if I'll do it like that ((AppCompatActivity)mContext).registerForActivityResult() it won't work ?

Comment: That will only work if `mContext` is actually an `AppCompatActivity`. If it is, great!